# GeckoDriver and InternetExplorerDriver always open new window instead of a new tab when I click link, ChromeDriver behaves normally

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, internet-explorer-driver

ChromeDriver works as expected, when the driver clicks a link that should open a new tab it opens the new tab.
This is different with GeckoDriver and InternetExplorerDriver, they always open new window, regardless that when I click these links by myself the new tab is opened as expected.

This is how I click links:

```
Driver.FindElement(selector).Click();
```

How to make FF and IE make open new tab when link is clicked when in automated mode? In other words make them behave the same as when I manually click these links.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default behavior via `FirefoxOptions`

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.SetPreference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 1);

WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Comment: I've tried 1,2 and 3, but I get: `ArgumentException: Preference browser.link.open_newwindow may not be overridden: frozen value=2, requested value=3`

Comment: Solved that, `SetPreference` should be invoked on `FirefoxOptions` object.

Comment: @Yoda found a [ticket](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5540), do it with `FirefoxOptions.SetPreference`

Comment: Yes, that's why I was able to fix that : ), thank you. Now the IE part.

Comment: @Yoda It should be the same

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't, however I'm investigating it right now again.

Comment: @Yoda Try `options = InternetExplorerOptions options.AddAdditionalCapability("browser.link.open_newwindow", 1)`

Comment: That;s the first thing I tried. Checked it, it still opens new windows.

Comment: @Yoda I'm not able to find a way to do it, I also encountered several posts regarding actions IE is not allowing, like setting download location. Nothing about this issue specifically, but it makes me wonder.